# Array.forEach() method not working with an array containing text elements

Tags: javascript, arrays, foreach, fetch

I'm in the process of learning how to make fetch api calls and return an array with a list of certain usernames. In the below code that I've written, the array that I was looking for seems to have been generated fine. However, when I try using .forEach() method on the array, it just does not seem to work. If I change the array contents to simple numbers like 1,2,3 etc, the .forEach() method seems to work as expected. Please let me know what am I missing out here? Thanks!

```
function getUsers() {
  let returnArray = [];
  fetch("https://api.github.com/users")
    .then((data) => data.json())
    .then((data) => {
      data.forEach((item) => {
        returnArray.push(item.login);
      });
    });

  return returnArray;
}

function createListItem(text) {
  let li = document.createElement("li");
  li.textConent = text;
  return li;
}

function addUsersToDOM() {
  let body = document.getElementById("my-body");

  namesArray = getUsers();
  console.log(namesArray); //Getting an array with the text elements

  namesArray.forEach((item) => {
    console.log(item); // Console log of individual text elements not working
  });
}

addUsersToDOM();
```

If I change the array contents to simple numbers like 1,2,3 etc, the .forEach() method seems to work as expected.

Comment: Did you use the debugger? You can see what data actually contains before you loop through it to see if it matches your expectations.

Comment: The issue is likely because the `getUsers()` function is asynchronous, meaning that it does not return the `returnArray` array immediately. Instead, the `returnArray` is only available after the fetch call has completed.

Answer (score 1):

You need to turn your `addUsersToDOM()` function into an `async` function:

```js
function getUsers(){
  return fetch("https://api.github.com/users")
    .then(data => data.json())
    .then(data => data.map(item=>item.login));
}

async function addUsersToDOM() {
  namesArray = await getUsers();
  console.log(namesArray);
}

addUsersToDOM();
```

I also changed the inner `.forEach()` loop into a `.map()`. This makes it easier to generate an array of login names.

Alternatively you can of course also work with the `.then()` method:

```js
function getUsers(){
  return fetch("https://api.github.com/users")
    .then(data => data.json())
    .then(data => data.map(item=>item.login));
}

function addUsersToDOM() {
  getUsers().then(console.log);
}

addUsersToDOM();
```

In either case you need to acknowledge that `getUsers()` returns a promise and not a direct result.

Answer (score 0):

**namesArray = getUsers();**

It get result of **getUsers** before getting data of users. And you have empty array. You have to wait response by API and then put it in **namesArray**

You can achieve this in the following way

```js
function getUsers() {
  let returnArray = [];
  // return Promise
  return fetch("https://api.github.com/users")
    .then((data) => data.json())
    .then((data) => {
      data.forEach((item) => {
        returnArray.push(item.login);
      });
      // return result by API
      return returnArray;
    });


}

function createListItem(text) {
  let li = document.createElement("li");
  li.textConent = text;
  return li;
}

// async before function
async function addUsersToDOM() {
  let body = document.getElementById("my-body");

  // await for waiting result
  namesArray = await getUsers();
  console.log('namesArray', namesArray); //Getting an array with the text elements

  namesArray.forEach((item) => {
    console.log(item); // Console log of individual text elements not working
  });
}

addUsersToDOM();
```